# Java ME: javascript supported or not?

Tags: java-me

I have Nokia S40 6th edition devices. So, is that all S40 devices support JavaScript?
Because I am calling one URL(ad.doubleclick.net/.../...) using HttpConnection and it was return JavaScript coded text So my S40 devices display only below things

> `<!--  // -->`

So, anyone can know why this is happening?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No S40 device supports Javascript within Java ME apps.  Some may support it in the native web browser.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. In my case, it will return the JavaScript code text(document.write("something text is here")) then what will I do? I want to extract that text from return response value.

Comment: Well you could write some code to parse the string out of that statement, but it will only work for that case.  You should create your own bespoke protocol for your app and forget about javascript altogether.